# Strongloop: loopback create nested structured model

Tags: strongloop

How to create model with nested structure?
Example:
 {
   parent
   {
      Child
      {
         Leaf
      }
   }
 }

Comment: { parent { Child { Leaf } } }

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **relations** between models. 
Using the structure you metioned:

1. each Parent **hasMany** Child
2. each Child **belongsTo** Parent and **hasMany** Leaf
3. each Leaf **belongsTo** Child

To create relations you can use the Loopback Relation Generator in the terminal: `slc loopback:relation`

See this github repo where I demonstrate how this works: https://github.com/jeserodz/loopback-nested-relations-example

And also see the official documentation for this feature: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Creating-model-relations.html